# Which table provide live "Waiting Call" status from asterisk database?

Tags: mysql, asterisk

Actually I want to make live statistics using **`asterisk`** database in another Server.
I already get live data from **`vicidial_live_agents`** table for -

- Agent Ready
- Agent In Call
- Agent Available
- Agent on Pause etc

By using **`status`** field value `'READY', 'QUEUE', 'INCALL', 'PAUSED', 'CLOSER','MQUEUE'` in my SQL Query.

Now I want to check **Incoming Waiting call** in IVR.

> How can I check `Incoming Waiting call` status from asterisk database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the table name for `asterisk` database `IVR` call status.

By checking `vicidial_auto_calls` table.

> There is `status` field with value :

- `SENT`, `RINGING`, `LIVE`, `XFER`, `PAUSED`, `CLOSER`, `BUSY`, `DISCONNECT`, `IVR`